# Openpyxl Input List Items Into Excel Spreadsheet Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Is it possible to input a list into an Excel Spreadsheet column? I have a list with 250+ list items that I need to put into a spreadsheet column. I keep running into appending the list as a row, but I can't seem to input my list into a column. I have tried a few for loops following the general case for writing into a cell, but no luck. I am a beginner when it comes to coding, and have very basic Python knowledge and am learning as I go. I would really appreciate the help.

Ex: v = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Inputting list V into Column A

Comment: Please provide at least pieces of code to undertand what you want to achieve and what issue you have

Comment: @EricMathieu My apologies. I forgot to mention that I have almost all of my code complete and my last task was to input my list I produced from existing data into a column. My list v was just arbitrary for the possibility of being able to make a general case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using OpenPyXl where val_list is your list of values:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("path to workbook file")
ws = wb["Sheet name"] # or wb[sheet_index]

for col, val in zip(ws.iter_cols(min_col=col_index, max_col=col_index, min_row=starting_row, max_row=len(val_list + min_row), val_list):
    for cell in col:
        cell.value = val
```

First for loop iterates through value list and columns via zip().
min_col and max_col are equal so you are only working on one column.
min_row is up to you, could be 1 (it is 1-based indexing)
max_row should be the length of values assuming 1:1 length

Second for loop says for each cell in the column within the specified range, assign the cell's Excel value (cell.value) to be the corresponding value from the val_list.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and guidance. It took me sometime to get my code to work, but I was able to finish it up!